# Convert whole Pycharm Project File (Contains GUI) into application

Tags: django, user-interface, unix, pycharm

I was actually thinking if the whole Pycharm Project folder (which mainly contains GUI) can actually be converted into an application which in turn can be opened from any Unix server? This means to say that, whenever this application is launch, an automatic GUI will be created (let's say, on Chrome) if `python manage.py runserver` is commanded onto the same Unix server? Any comment and solution will be a great help, thank you.

Comment: Django is basically a frame work. So what you are asking is to change that into a desktop app, then you need to use tool command language. I have not used tk/tcl personally so can't tell much about it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I've actually decided to use PyInstaller, but this application can only be opened from its own server (i.e. 127.0.0.1), it can't be opened from any unix server. Thus, I'm still looking for a solution :/